# Facebook graph-api android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to request several fields from graph api.

Using the code below overwrites previous values.

```
params.putString("fields", "id");
params.putString("fields", "email");
params.putString("fields", "picture");
params.putString("fields", "birthday");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mFacebook.request("me",params));
```

However when I use

```
params.putStringArray("fields", new String[]{"id", "email", "picture", "birthday"});
```

produces:

```
Bundle[{fields=[Ljava.lang.String;@44a04bb8}]
```

Anyone faced this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GOT IT!!!
params.putString("fields", "id,email,gender");

Answer (score 3):

Use:
params.putString("fields", "id, email, picture, birthday");